# Making post requests from angular8

Tags: angular

I'm trying to make http post requests from angular but the requests aren't
 sent to the api, what am I doing wrong? and how can I save the response as a Json object?

```
import {HttpClient} from '@angular/common/http'
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})

export class ApiService {
  static url: string = 'api url...'
  constructor(public httpClient: HttpClient) { }
  addUser(fullName, gender, ID, phone, email, notes, pass) {
    let response
    return this.httpClient.post(ApiService.url, {
      "full_name": fullName,
      "gender": gender,
      "email": email,
      "id": ID,
      "phone": phone,
      "notes": notes,
      "password": pass
    })
  }}
```

Component:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {SignupForm} from '../signup-form'
import { ApiService } from "../api.service";

@Component({
  selector: 'app-signup',
  templateUrl: './signup.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./signup.component.css'],
})
export class SignupComponent implements OnInit {
  form = new SignupForm('', '', '', '','','','')
  submitted= false
  Response
  constructor(private logUser : ApiService) { }
  ngOnInit() {
  }
  getForm()
  {
    return JSON.stringify(this.form)
  }
  onSubmit()
  {
    this.submitted = true;
    this.Response = this.logUser.addUser(this.form.fullName, this.form.gender, this.form.ID,this.form.pass,this.form.email,this.form.notes,this.form.pass)
  }
}
```

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The addUser method in your service(ApiService) is returning an observable . so in order to manipulate the post api call response , you need to subscibe to it like below.

```
onSubmit()
  {
    this.submitted = true;
    this.logUser.addUser(this.form.fullName, this.form.gender, this.form.ID,this.form.pass,this.form.email,this.form.notes,this.form.pass).subscribe(resp =>  {this.Response = resp} )
  }
```

Comment: Thanks! But it’s still not getting to the api, (I can make requests in postman so I guess it’s something with the code)

Comment: it's saying [Error] XMLHttpRequest cannot load 'url' due to access control checks.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to subscribe to post call
Do it like this

```
 this.logUser.addUser(this.form.fullName, this.form.gender, this.form.ID,this.form.pass,this.form.email,this.form.notes,this.form.pass)
.subscribe( data => {
            this.Response = data;
            }
```